# Oauth Invalid auth/bad request (got a 404, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)

Tags: magento, oauth

Im trying to list all the products using rest api. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/rest/introduction.html). When I access this url "http://yourhost.com/oauth_customer.php" it takes me to authorization page and I got oauth token and oauth secret key. But when I click on authorize button I got this error "Invalid auth/bad request (got a 404, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)".

***Oauth details.***

PLAINTEXT support   enabled

RSA-SHA1 support    enabled

HMAC-SHA1 support   enabled

Request engine support  php_streams, curl

source version  $Id: oauth.c 325799 2012-05-24 21:07:51Z jawed $

version     1.2.3

Comment: Possible lead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148145/magento-rest-api-user-given-admin-role-but-only-granted-guest-access/18627708

Answer (score -1):

In my case I had to add a limit to make it work
/api/rest/products?limit=100
however I'm still looking for a solution to retrieve all the products, just like in the SOAP call.